# 4 panel div not formating correctly

Tags: html, css

I want to create a page laid out as

```
|right panel|______toppanel________|left panel   |
|           |Cesium Container      |             |
|           |                      |             |
|           |                      |             |
|           |                      |             |
|           |______________________|             |
|           |Bottom Panel          |             |
|           |                      |             |
|           |                      |             |
```

but with this CSS

```
<style>
   @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
   #cesiumContainer {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      left: 14.7%;
      height: 65%;
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
   }
   div
   {
       border: 3px solid; 
       border-color:3300FF;
   }
   body 
   {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      height:100%;          
   }
   #rightpanel
   {
      top:0;
      height: 100%;
      float:right;
      right: 0;
      width: 14.7%;
       margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    #leftpanel
    {
      top: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: 14.5%;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
     }
     #bottompanel
     {
        height: 10%;
      width: 50%;
      bottom:0%;
      left:20%;
       margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      posistion: absolute;
   }
   #fullpage
   {
       position:absolute;
       top:0;
       bottom:0;
       left:0;
       right:0;
       overflow:hidden;
       z-index:-1
    }
    html
    {
      min-height:100%;
      position:relative;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div id="rightpanel">
            <p> hii Right panel</p>
        </div>
        <div id ="leftpanel">
            <p> hii Left panel</p>
        </div>
        <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
        <div id= "bottompanel">
            <p> hii Bottom panel</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

The bottom div won't sit between the two side panels and instead its pushed to the bottom of the two panels and therefore gets pushed off the page because they are at 100%.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y5LER/)

Comment: you have a typo in #bottompanel{ posistion: absolute; }   http://jsfiddle.net/h3uaC/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4chcT/ check this:)

Comment: Thanks. Spelling will be the death of me one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JuanC is correct.

Your typo `posistion: absolute;` in `#bottompanel` is the culprit.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xBbh5/) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Your #bottompanel has a typo. It says `posistion: absolute;` in stead of `position: absolute;`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a better way to find your desired layout. Just putting this out there.

[JSBin Example!](http://jsbin.com/fakojazi/1/edit)

HTML (A little messy as we don't want spaces, a side effect of `display: inline-block;`)

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="leftSide"></div><div id="middle"><div id="header"></div><div id="content"></div><div id="footer"></div></div><div id="rightSide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#wrap div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#leftSide, #rightSide {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #F00;
}
#middle {
    width: 60%;
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 30%;
    background: #FF0;
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    height: 40%;
    background: #F30;
    width: 100%;
}
#footer {
    height: 30%;
    background: #FF0;
    width: 100%;
}
```